# Выборка из XML средствами PHP

Tags: xml, php

Доброго вам времени суток! Возможно, задам вопрос очень глупый, не точный. Надо разобрать XML файл, с помощью уже встроенных функций в ядро, но вот чего-то не догоняю, занервничал уже. На JS и Flash знаю как, но в пхп это нечто другое.
Есть XMl файл :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<setup_>
    <cat title="Основные">
        <comp type="select" title="Регистрация открыта?">
            <conf title="да" val="yes"></conf>
            <conf title="нет" val="no"></conf>
        </comp>
        <comp type="select" title="Активация пользователей">
            <conf title="автоматичесская" val="auto"></conf>
            <conf title="по решению администратора" val="with_allow"></conf>
        </comp>
    </cat>
</setup_>
```

Подскажите, полный код, как мне получить в переменную `$cats` массив из тегов `<cat>`, в `$comps` массив из тегов `<comp>` и как обратиться к их свойствам? P.S. Либо я тупой, либо нет, но гугл, яндекс и прочие шалости использовал, ничего адекватного не нашёл, код увидеть не тороплюсь, поэтому хотелось бы увидеть самый полный код начиная с `<?php` и заканчивая `?>`
заранее спасибо...

Comment: Если не хотите тупо ждать пока вам напишут полный код - подскажу...<br>
Для чтения копайте в сторону `simplexml` расширения ;)

Comment: И его смотрел, не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо действительно плохо искали. Исчерпывающие примеры есть даже в [официальной документации](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic).

```
$setup = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

// итерация по элементам cat
foreach ($setup->cat as $cat) {

    // доступ к аттрибутам
    echo $cat['title']."\n";

    // итерация по дочерним элементам comp 
    foreach ($cat->comp as $comp) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я делал так
XML файл имел следующую структуру

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AscColorl.xsd" generated="2011-09-27T09:13:12">
    <ColorsAll>
    <COLORID>531</COLORID>
    <COLOR>#005868</COLOR>
    <GAMMA>859</GAMMA>
    <DMC>-</DMC>
    <ANCHOR>-</ANCHOR>
    <MADEIRA>-</MADEIRA>
    </ColorsAll>
    ...
</dataroot>
```

обявляем переменную

```
$str = file_get_contents("XMLS/AscColor/AscColorl.xml");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
```

вывести нужно было в виде таблицы,

```
<table width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#666666" bgcolor="#F5F5F5" >
<tbody>
<?php
        foreach ($xml->ColorsAll as $ColorsAll)
    {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td width="72"><p align="center"><?php echo "{$ColorsAll->COLORID}" ?></p></td>
        <td width="72"><p align="center"><?php echo "{$ColorsAll->GAMMA}" ?></p></td>
        <td width="72"><p align="center"><?php echo "{$ColorsAll->DMC}" ?></p></td>
        <td width="72"><p align="center"><?php echo "{$ColorsAll->ANCHOR}" ?></p></td>
        <td width="72"><p align="center"><?php echo "{$ColorsAll->MADEIRA}" ?></p></td>
        <td width="106" bgcolor=<?php echo "{$ColorsAll->COLOR}" ?>><p align="center"></p></td></tr><?php
    }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

вот и весь пример, если принцип понятен можете попробовать свою задачу решить сами

Answer (score 1):

Есть очень мощный инструмент поиска по XML. Называется DOMXPath (см. доку по PHP https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domxpath.php). Разбираете XML контент с помощью DOMDocument а дальше конструируете запрос и выбираете нужные узлы. Запросы строятся даже с использованием значений атрибутов.